# ASP.NET MVC submit form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, performance, post

I know two ways of submitting form data: by having a button of type submit or by an AJAX post call. What is the difference between those two regarding performace?

Comment: Kind of vague... Depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to post data from view to controller.. all form data..

Comment: then both methods work.

Comment: @dan89 , So what is your question ?

Comment: Better to learn from http://www.asp.net website about the performance of any.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very general question, so here is a very general answer.

If you implement the AJAX call efficiently on the server, then you can expect AJAX to be more performant (when measured on the server) than a full page round-trip.

For instance, if you use ASP.NET, clicking a button to submit a page will cause a POST of the form data and a complete re-buildup and rendering of the page. That is not necessary with an AJAX call, if you use real AJAX and not the Microsoft AJAX Control Toolkit for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax POST**

Ajax post prevents reload and postback.İt sends data to controller.

**Form Data**

İt occurs reload page and postback.İt sends data to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `Html.BeginForm`. It will prevent the full postback and will improve the performance.